# Resolving permission error in sql for username domain\computerName$

Tags: permissions, sql-server

I'm trying to resolve a permission error on our sharepoint sql server. The login for the user that has failed is the WFE computer name on the farm config db. What permission or role can I grant that would target this?

UPDATE:

> SQL Database 'Farm_Config' on SQL Server instance 'SQLSERVER'
>   not found. Additional error information from SQL Server is included
>   below.
>
> Cannot open database "Farm_Config" requested by the login. The
>   login failed. Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\COMPUTERNAME$'.

Comment: can you share the error?

Answer (score 1):

Can you check whether your IIS AppPools are running as Network Service or LocalSystem? If so - it's probably a good idea to change those and use a domain account instead of permissioning your Web Front Ends to access SharePoint Databases. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806438/login-failed-for-user-domain-machinename) thread for details.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying to associate the permission error report to a cause or related symptom of a problem.

The [Microsoft TechNet article on Event ID 3760](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513043(v=office.14).aspx), Alert Name:Database could not be accessed mentions a number of symptoms and resolutions for a similar error. Here is an excerpt:

> **Symptoms**:   The following symptoms might appear:
>
> - Content in the database is not available and attempts to access the database generate errors.
> - This event appears in the event log: Event ID: 3760 Description: SQL Database '' on SQL Server instance '' not found. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.
>
> **Cause**:   One or more of the following might cause this:.
>
> - The SQL Server user login failed.
> - The database has been deleted or renamed.
> - The database is currently unavailable because it is in an offline or loading state.
>
> **Resolution:   Verify that SQL Server is running**
>
> - On the database server, in the Services snap-in, verify that the SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service is running.
>
> **Resolution:   Verify that the user account can connect to SQL Server**
>
> - Log onto Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio as the account provided in the error details and click Connect and then Database Engine.
>     Type the server name provided in the error details and click Connect.
>
> **Resolution:   Verify that the database exists**
>
> - In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, expand the server node.
>     Expand the Databases node.